# How to generate non-random dictionary passwords using Python?

Tags: python

After I broke up with my girlfriend I changed a password of mine into :

"MyEx-GirlFriendIsAnInsult"   (yeah that's childish)

I used upper scale, lower scale, numbers and special characters but I can't recall where I put those now.

I want to build a script that generates every possible combinations of "MyEx-GirlFriendIsAnInsult"

where for instance, "E" could be either "E", "e", "3", "i" could be either "i", "1", "!" and so on.

Does a python library that could help me exist in such case ?

How can I proceed ? I am totally lost and I don't know where to start (python beginners, and this is going to be one of my first study case).

Thanks !

Comment: Python brut force is probably not the best solution. What is the password for? (email, pc, phone etc.)

Comment: This could actually be written quite easily without a library (but probably no one here would write it for you). Basically replace the string by a list of lists where for each character a list of possible replacement characters is given. Then use `itertools.product` to create all possible values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's for a web portal. I don't mean to brute-force the portal using the script, but I only want to generate the dictionary. I roughly know the phrase I'm looking for and where upper scale letters, special characters could be. I don't believe it makes a lot of combinations in total. What other options would you recommend ?

Comment: If you search for an existing software for this, please try at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: Run a nested for loop, outer loop iterating over each character and inner loop using `lower()` and `upper()` to make every combination of letters. This will probably take minutes to complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael ! I'm aware my request is quite basic and that no one would write it for me. Your advice helped me a lot thouh as I know where to start now. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by setting up a list with all the possible character substitutions. To keep it brief I shortened your example, and you would of course want to build it in code, not specify the list as a literal:

```
mylist = ["Mm", "yY", "Gg", "I1i" , "rR", "Ll", "Fr", "Ii1", "Ee3", "nN", "dD"]
```

Once you have all of the options, use `itertools` to get the product of all of these options:

```
import itertools
for f in itertools.product(*mylist): 
    print (''.join(f))
```

This gives:

```
MyGIrLFRIEnd
MyGIrLFRIEnD
... 13,820 more ..
mYgiRlfr13Nd
mYgiRlfr13ND
```

Comment: Thanks BoarGules ! This is a good base and I will work it a bit. I should have specified it, but as I already know that every first letters of words are upper scale and that others are lower scale or special characters or numbers, the difficulty is actually to reduce the amount of possibilities keeping this in mind.

Comment: Then adjust `mylist` to reflect the real constraints you know to exist. I couldn't guess them, so I ended up with far more possibilities.

Comment: You nailed it BoarGules ! Thank you so much ! I'm just ashamed I did not figure it out myself

Answer (score 1):

You can define a dictionary, key as uppercase characters and value as all possible combination of that character.

```
rand_dict = {
    "A": ["@", "a", "A"],
    "B": ["b", "3", "B"],
    "C": ["c", "(", "C"],
    "D": ["D", "d", "6"],
    "E": ["E", "e"],
    "F": ["F", "f"],
    "G": ["6", "G", "g", "9"],
    "H": ["h", "H"],
    "I": ["I", "i", "!"],
    "J": ["J", "j"],
    "K": ["k", "K"],
    "L": ["l", "L", "1"],
    "M": ["m", "M"],
    "N": ["n", "N"],
    "O": ["O", "o", "0"],
    "P": ["p", "P"],
    "Q": ["Q", "q"],
    "R": ["R", "r"],
    "S": ["s", "S", "$"],
    "T": ["T", "t"],
    "U": ["U", "u"],
    "V": ["v", "V", "<"],
    "W": ["w", "W"],
    "X": ["x", "X"],
    "Y": ["Y", "y"],
    "Z": ["z", "Z"],
}
```

shuffle the all possible list by looping the string

```
foo = "MyExGirlFriendIsAnInsult"

bar = []
for i in list(foo.upper()):
    random.shuffle(rand_dict[i], random.random)
    bar.append(rand_dict[i][0])

print("".join(bar))
```

output as like:

```
Myex9Ir1fR!EnD!s@NInsulT
myEXGiRLfRIeNdI$AnIN$uLT
MYEX6Irlfrien6!$aNInsUlt
MYEXG!R1fr!ENdISAn!nSu1t
myExg!rLFrIEn6is@NiN$u1T
```

Comment: Thanks SACHIN CHAVAN. That's a good idea. The solution BoarGules gave me suits more to my specific case, but I keep yours for a future case.

Comment: Thanks @CurtisOnTheRoad

Comment: highly highly don't recommend doing this, do like a combination of this and BoarGules answer, since random shuffling will NOT provide all results.